# Using a string variable to set value of .NumberFormat in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to set a custom number format with the following result:
the value "22,800" becomes "Europe: 22.8 M"

I can achieve this using the number formatting window, and using:
"Europe:" #,##0.0, "M"; "Europe:" -#,##0.0, "M"

I can also achieve this in VBA window using 
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = """Europe:"" #,##0.0, ""M""; ""Europe:"" -#,##0.0, ""M"""

Here is the issue: I'm running a loop function which takes the values from different sheets and pastes them onto a summary sheet - I need the region (e.g. "Europe") to show up next to the number, but I don't want to write the code for the loop function 9 different times for my 9 regions.

My attempted solution, here I would just change the value of the variable "region" for each loop:

```
Dim region As String
Dim numformat As String
region = "Europe"
numformat = Chr(34) + Chr(34) + Chr(34) + region + ":" + Chr(34) + Chr(34) + " #,##0.0, " + Chr(34) + Chr(34) + "M" + Chr(34) + Chr(34) + "; " + Chr(34) + Chr(34) + region + ":" + Chr(34) + Chr(34) + " -#,##0.0, " + Chr(34) + Chr(34) + "M" + Chr(34) + Chr(34) + Chr(34)
Selection.NumberFormat = numformat
```

Which formats the number as "Europe: #,##0.0, M; Europe: -#,##0.0, M" - it doesnt show the number at all, just this string.

However, if I use ?numformat in the immediate window to return the string's value, and then copy/paste that value so that 
Selection.NumberFormat = """Europe:"" #,##0.0, ""M""; ""Europe:"" -#,##0.0, ""M"""

Then, I get the correct number format, "Europe: 22.8 M"

But this doesn't help me, because now the region name is hard-coded again. Can anyone help identify what I'm doing wrong, or identify an alternative solution?

Cheers,

B

Comment: Is the region formatting present in the source data?

Comment: The source data is formatted in standard number format with thousands separator and no decimals. It needs to remain this way. The region is the name of each tab.

Comment: You can create a Const String like `Const MasterNumFormat = """<CURR>:"" #,##0.0, ""M"";""<CURR>:"" -#,##0.0, ""M"""` then use `numformat = Replace(MasterNumFormat,"<CURR>",region)` instead of constructing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
    numFormat = """" & region & ": ""#,##0.0,""M"";""" & region & ":"" -#,##0.0, ""M"""
```

or, if you really want to use `Chr(34)` you don't need to double them, because you don't need to escape them:

```
numFormat = Chr(34) & region & ": " & Chr(34) & "#,##0.0," & Chr(34) & "M" & Chr(34) & ";" & Chr(34) & region & ":" & Chr(34) & " -#,##0.0, " & Chr(34) & "M" & Chr(34)
```

Comment: Thanks Rory! Works like a charm. I figured it was just an error with my syntax. I realize now, after reading your answer, that since my variable numFormat is already a string type, I don't need to enclose it in quotation marks when setting it as the value for NumberFormat. Which in turn means that I don't need the double quotes to delimit the text within the number format.